# Wordpress how can I do something like this?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

on my index page I have Featured Content Gallery,I want to put Dynamic Content Gallery when I open some category(for example category named myCat),like there is another index.php page but it is start page of category myCat.What is the best way to do this,to add extra php file to theme?Some more ideas?Tnx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try to use shortcode

Comment: I know what are shorcodes,but dont know how to do with shortcodes,any examples?